# Image cropper in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have searched everywhere but didn't got a single documentation about cropping images in Jetpack Compose
*How to crop Image in Jetpack Compose?*

Comment: You need to build a Cropper by yourself or you can integrate some library which does that for you . I m quite sure you can integrate it with Compose . have you tried anything ?

Comment: Nope But there are lots of libraries out there but for `XML` not for Jetpack Compose

Comment: Post an example

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: I am also looking for some thing how we can crop the image in compose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I built one for Jetpack Compose that can crop with static, dynamic overlays with animations and custom shapes and many customization options.

It's production ready now, but still some features in progress and in to-do
If you would like to test it out, help with issues, here is the link

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Cropper

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun MainContent(
    cropProperties: CropProperties,
    cropStyle: CropStyle,
    onSelectionPageMenuClicked: (SelectionPage) -> Unit
) {

    val imageBitmapLarge = ImageBitmap.imageResource(
        LocalContext.current.resources,
        R.drawable.landscape1
    )

    var imageBitmap by remember { mutableStateOf(imageBitmapLarge) }
    var croppedImage by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }


    var crop by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isCropping by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.DarkGray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            ImageCropper(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f),
                imageBitmap = imageBitmap,
                contentDescription = "Image Cropper",
                cropStyle = cropStyle,
                cropProperties = cropProperties,
                crop = crop,
                onCropStart = {
                    isCropping = true
                }
            ) {
                croppedImage = it
                isCropping = false
                crop = false
                showDialog = true
            }
        }

        BottomAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart),
            actions = {


                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        onSelectionPageMenuClicked(SelectionPage.Properties)
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.Settings,
                        contentDescription = "Settings",
                    )

                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        onSelectionPageMenuClicked(SelectionPage.Style)
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Brush, contentDescription = "Style")
                }

                IconButton(
                    onClick = { crop = true }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Crop, contentDescription = "Crop Image")
                }
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ImageSelectionButton(
                    elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(defaultElevation = 0.dp),
                    onImageSelected = { bitmap: ImageBitmap ->
                        imageBitmap = bitmap
                    }
                )
            }
        )

        if (isCropping) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }

    if (showDialog) {
        croppedImage?.let {
            ShowCroppedImageDialog(imageBitmap = it) {
                showDialog = !showDialog
                croppedImage = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to install it? I followed the instructions on the GitHub project README but in Android Studio, it shows can't resolve this dependency ...

Answer (score 13):

You can actually just use those older Android libraries no problem.

I used this one: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
implementation("com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.0.0")
```

Usage (CropImageContract is provided by the above):

```
@Composable
fun ImageSelectorAndCropper() {
    var imageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val bitmap =  remember {
        mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)
    }

    val imageCropLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
        if (result.isSuccessful) {
            // use the cropped image
            imageUri = result.uriContent
        } else {
            // an error occurred cropping
            val exception = result.error
        }
    }

    val imagePickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        val cropOptions = CropImageContractOptions(uri, CropImageOptions())
        imageCropLauncher.launch(cropOptions)
    }

    if (imageUri != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
            bitmap.value = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, imageUri)
        } else {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, imageUri!!)
            bitmap.value = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
        }
        Button(onClick = { imagePickerLauncher.launch("image/*") }) {
            Text("Pick image to crop")
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I also had to add this to the manifest so that the CropActivity picks up a theme

```
<activity android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

Comment: I have to use androidx.appcompat:appcompat to get it working with compose. Could you give an example of using this with camera. Like launching camera and using its pic to crop. Thanks