# Crop image after capturing using camerax and jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I want to implement an screen which is camera preview, with a Rectangle in the middle of screen represebting the area to the user to put image inside that rectangle. Then I want the captured image to be cropped to the size of the rectangle in the middle. Please help me to implement this feature.

[image]

Comment: elaborate on your question. so I can help you

Comment: @ChiragThummar I want user to take picture of their ID card and I want to crop the captured image to the size of the rectangle shown on the screen (as I uploaded the image in the main question). The camera preview is in AndroidView and the rectangle in the middle screen is a box. all these components are inside another box. The challenge is to find the exact size and points of the rectangle and crop the captured bitmap.

Comment: you can use openCV for detecting rectangular shape and crop it

Comment: what you need seems pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70527505/1332549 right?

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC Not exactly this, but I want to crop image immediately after being captured and then I want to show the cropped image to the user. The problem is to recognize the rectangle box on the screen and crop the captured bitmap according to the box size and points.